# What is wrong with this program? Syntax error in print() function python

Tags: python

Why do I get syntax error in line 18? There is something wrong with the `print()` function, IDE says, but I can't figure out what exactly. I'm porting this program from C to Python as I'm learning the latter.

```
#caesar encipher
import sys
import cs50


if len(sys.argv)!= 2:
    print("Nope")

k = int(sys.argv[1])

if k<0:
    print("Nope")

else:
    code = cs50.get_string()
    #add k letters to each character in the string. For example is code[0]='a' and k=3, program will return 'd'.
    for i in code:
        if code[i].islower():
            new_code = chr((((ord(code[i]+k)- 97)% 26)+ 97)
            print(f"{new_code}")
        elif code[i].isupper():
            new_code = chr((((ord(code[i]+k)- 65)% 26)+ 65)
            print(f"{new_code}")
        else:
            print(code[i])
        print()
```

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? f strings are a fairly new addition to the language.

Comment: You are missing a `)` (or open one `(` to much) in the lines beginning with `new_code = chr((((`

Comment: It should be `new_code = chr((((ord(code[i]+k)- 97)% 26)+ 97))` You are missing a pharantases

Answer (score -1):

It must be like this

```
#caesar encipher
import sys
import cs50


if len(sys.argv)!= 2:
    print("Nope")

k = int(sys.argv[1])

if k<0:
    print("Nope")

else:
    code = cs50.get_string()
    #add k letters to each character in the string. For example is code[0]='a' and k=3, program will return 'd'.
    for i in code:
        if code[i].islower():
            new_code = chr((((ord(code[i]+k)- 97)% 26)+ 97))
            print("{new_code}")
        elif code[i].isupper():
            new_code = chr((((ord(code[i]+k)- 65)% 26)+ 65))
            print("{new_code}")
        else:
            print(code[i])
        print()
```

Comment: This is not a correct answer, you removed the f-strings and no proper output formatting at all is done now.